# What is the diffrence between the Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack and Microsoft.Bcl.Async?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, nuget, async-await

I was searching NuGet to find the libary that allows you to use async/await with .net 4.0 project. I was originally looking for [Async for .NET Framework 4, Silverlight 4 and 5, and Windows Phone 7.5 and 8](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) however I found [Async Targeting Pack for Visual Studio 11](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack) instead.

What is the difference between those two packages and when should I use which?

> **Async for .NET Framework 4, Silverlight 4 and 5, and Windows Phone 7.5 and 8**
>
> This package enables Visual Studio 2012 projects targeting .NET
> Framework 4 (with KB2468871), Silverlight 4 and 5, and Windows Phone
> 7.5 (including any portable library combinations) to use the new 'async' and 'await' keywords. This package also includes Task-based
> extension methods that allow using some of the existing asynchronous
> APIs with the new language keywords. Windows Phone 8 projects can use
> this package to get access to async extension methods for the
> networking types.
>
> This package is not supported in Visual Studio 2010, and is only required for projects targeting .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET for Windows Store apps when consuming a library that uses this package. For known issues, please see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx.

> **Async Targeting Pack for Visual Studio 11**
>
> The "Async Targeting Pack for Visual Studio 11" enables projects targeting .NET Framework
> 4.0 or Silverlight 5 to use the Async language feature in C# and Visual Basic.
>
> This pack requires Visual Studio 11 and will not work with Visual
> Studio 2010.
>
> The pack contains the API support necessary to use the 'async' and
> 'await' keywords in C# 5.0 and Visual Basic 11, as well as a set of
> Task-based adapter APIs that allow using some of the existing
> asynchronous APIs with the new language keywords.
>
> This targeting pack is not required for projects targeting .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET for Metro style apps. It is only required for projects targeting Silverlight 5 and .NET Framework 4.0. Earlier platform releases are not supported.

Answer (score 2):

`Microsoft.Bcl.Async` supersedes `Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack`. The targeting pack was left in NuGet so people who already used it can still re-download it for their projects.

See [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/04/17/microsoft-bcl-async-is-now-stable.aspx) for more info.